# Why does $.get () not seem to trigger a .ajaxStart()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code:

```
$("body")
    .ajaxStart(function () {
        $(this).css({ 'cursor': 'progress !important' })
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
        $(this).css({ 'cursor': 'default !important' })
    });
```

When I issue this the code works but it seems not to trigger the cursor change:

```
       $.get(href)
            .success(function (content) {
               // code here
            })
            .fail(function (ajaxContext) {
               // code here
            });
```

Do I need to specifically use $.ajax to trigger the .ajaxStart ?

Update: I just changed to !important.

Comment: What is `this` in that context?

Comment: @alex: It's the `body`, i.e., the selected element `$("body")`.

Comment: More importantly - What is this in `that` context. Oh wait ..

Comment: Copy-pasting this and adding an `alert`, it seems to [work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/DVBU3/). I expect that the request finishes too quickly for you to notice the cursor change. :-)

Comment: Gijs - Thanks you might be right here. I am still trying to check things out. I thought it was because of the way I was calling ajax.

Comment: Don't forget that if any other element has a styled cursor it will override the bodys cursor. [Small example](http://jsfiddle.net/jLhj6/)

Comment: What version of jQuery are you running?